# Xlsxwriter autofilter TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

Getting a error when I try to use the autofilter in xlsxwriter, trying to pass through a column of a dataframe and hide rows that are not blanks. Data are words and not numbers. I followed https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_autofilters.html but doesn't appear to work for what i'm trying to do. It fails on `worksheet1.write_row(row, 8, row_data)`

TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

```
worksheet1.filter_column(8, "Status == Blanks")
row = 1
for row_data in df_owners["Status"]:
    ic(row_data)
    status = row_data
# Check for rows that match the filter.
if status == "Blanks":
    # Row matches the filter, display the row as normal.
    pass
else:
    # We need to hide rows that don't match the filter.
    worksheet1.set_row(row, options={"hidden": True})
worksheet1.write_row(row, 8, row_data)

# Move on to the next worksheet row.
row += 1
```

Comment: what is `df_owners`?

Comment: @drum a dataframe

Comment: show minimum reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to hide rows from a Pandas dataframe to match the filter then it would be better to use Pandas to figure out which rows to hide.

Here is an example based on your code and on the description that you want to hide rows that aren't blank, i.e., to show elements in the filtered column that are blank.

Something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Create a sample dataframe.
df = pd.DataFrame({'Status': ["Foo", "", "Bar", "", "Bay", "", "Baz"],
                   'Data': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]})

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_autofilter.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# Get the dimensions of the dataframe.
(max_row, max_col) = df.shape

# Make the columns wider for clarity.
worksheet.set_column(0,  max_col - 1, 12)

# Set the autofilter.
worksheet.autofilter(0, 0, max_row, max_col - 1)

# Add a filter criteria.
worksheet.filter_column(0, 'Status == Blanks')

# It isn't enough to just apply the criteria. The rows that don't match
# must also be hidden. We use Pandas to figure our which rows to hide.
for row_num in (df.index[(df['Status'] != '')].tolist()):
    worksheet.set_row(row_num + 1, options={'hidden': True})

writer.close()
```

Output:

[image]

The is a similar [example](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_autofilter.html) in the XlsxWriter docs.